# Django all auth with access token, what settings to test? (for app)

Tags: android, django, facebook-login, django-allauth

My usecase: Let the user login from his android app & get the access token, then pass it to django. More specifically to the code below.
I have added my app's client ID and token using django admin (ie localhost/admin)

My code

```
def facebook_login(request):

access_token = request.POST['access_token']

print(access_token)

from allauth.socialaccount import providers
from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialLogin, SocialToken, SocialApp
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook.views import fb_complete_login
from allauth.socialaccount.helpers import complete_social_login
try:
    app = SocialApp.objects.get(provider="facebook")
    print(app)
    token = SocialToken(app=app,
                        token=access_token)
    print(token)
    login = fb_complete_login(app, token)
    login.token = token
    print(login)
    login.state = SocialLogin.state_from_request(request)
    ret = complete_social_login(request, login)
    print(ret)
    #if we get here we've succeeded
    return HttpResponse("success")
except:
    # FIXME: Catch only what is needed
    return HttpResponse("failed")
```

How do I test if this works on my local machine? What settings do I need?

Doing

```
c=Client()
r=c.post('/login/',{'access_token':'adadasfvaera10238123094572zwcd'})
```

always fails for any access token I get from facebook. Where do I put in my application Id to enable this?

Comment: hey did you get this to work? I'm struggling with the same thing